SIMD: matrix slicing performance
I want to be able to take a "slice" of a matrix, a relatively common operation in linear algebra.
Superficially, it looks like the kind of algorithm that should benefit from SIMD - particularly as our indexes, are Ints. We go round a loop, compute an index, put it into a new array.
 extension (m : Matrix)
 inline def slice2(rowRange: List[Int], colRange: List[Int]): Matrix =
  val oldRows = range(rowRange, m.rows)
  val oldCols = range(colRange, m.cols)
  val numNewRows = oldRows.size
  val numNewcols = oldCols.size

  val newArr = NArray.ofSize[Double](oldCols.size * oldRows.size)
  var idx = 0
  while idx < newArr.size do
    val i = idx / numNewRows
    val colpos = oldCols(i)
    val stride = colpos * m.rows
    var j = idx % numNewRows
    val rowPos = oldRows(j)
    // println(s"i: $i || j: $j ${stride + rowPos} ")
    newArr(idx) = m.raw(stride + rowPos)
    idx += 1
  end while
  Matrix(newArr, (oldRows.size, oldCols.size))(using BoundsCheck.DoBoundsCheck.no)
end slice2

Here's the implementation.
extension (m : Matrix)
inline def apply(rowRange: RangeExtender, colRange: RangeExtender): Matrix =
  val oldRows: Array[Int] = range(rowRange, m.rows)
  val oldCols: Array[Int] = range(colRange, m.cols)
  val numNewRows = oldRows.size
  val numNewcols = oldCols.size
  val newArr = NArray.ofSize[Double](numNewcols * numNewRows)

  val spd = DoubleVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED
  val spi = spd.withLanes(java.lang.Integer.TYPE)
  val l = spi.length()

  val rowsArr = IntVector.broadcast(spi, numNewRows)
  val oldRowsArr = IntVector.broadcast(spi, m.rows)

  var idx = 0
  while idx < spi.loopBound(newArr.size) do
    val indexes = IntVector.broadcast(spi, idx).addIndex(1)
    val iVec = indexes.div(rowsArr)
    val j_vec = indexes.sub(iVec.mul(rowsArr))

    val colStride = IntVector.fromArray(spi, oldCols, 0, iVec.toArray(), 0).mul(oldRowsArr)
    val oldRow = IntVector.fromArray(spi, oldRows, 0, j_vec.toIntArray(), 0)
    val toInsertIdx = colStride.add(oldRow)
    DoubleVector
      .fromArray(spd, m.raw, 0, toInsertIdx.toIntArray(), 0)
      .intoArray(newArr, idx)

    idx += l
  end while

  while idx < newArr.size do
    val i = idx / numNewRows
    val colpos = oldCols(i)
    val stride = colpos * m.rows
    var j = idx % numNewRows
    val rowPos = oldRows(j)
    // println(s"i: $i || j: $j ${stride + rowPos} ")
    newArr(idx) = m._1(stride + rowPos)
    idx += 1
  end while
  Matrix(newArr, (oldRows.size, oldCols.size))(using BoundsCheck.DoBoundsCheck.no)

end apply

It passes the tests, but the performance is... filthy.
Benchmark                     (len)   Mode  Cnt         Score          Error  Units
SlicingBenchmark.slice_loop2     10  thrpt    3  66054296.885 ± 11789323.861  ops/s
SlicingBenchmark.slice_vec       10  thrpt    3  11711099.686 ±  2576154.270  ops/s


Being roughly 6x slower, than a simple while loop. That disadvantage becomes more acute as matrix size increases, which tells me this isn't about setup cost. It appears this algorithm is significantly slower, vectorised.
I started taking it apart, to try and find out where, and to my astonishment, it appears to be this line.
According to my benchmark, just this
      var idx = 0
      while idx < spi.loopBound(newArr.size) do
        val indexes = IntVector.broadcast(spi, idx).addIndex(1)
        idx += l
      end while

runs slower than the entire looped version. In other words, it is slower to generate the indexes in vectorised form, than it is to execute the entire algorithm in a loop.
Woulds this be expected? I lean toward this being a "bug", but I am far out of my depth. Has anyone else had get similar results? Plus, the error bar is huge.
Benchmark                     (len)   Mode  Cnt       Score        Error  Units
SlicingBenchmark.slice_loop2     50  thrpt    3  707118.601 ± 204524.302  ops/s
SlicingBenchmark.slice_vec       50  thrpt    3  374814.713 ± 567035.529  ops/s


Okay, so this issue is the change of lanes. i.e. this.
    val spd = DoubleVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED
    val spi = spd.withLanes(java.lang.Integer.TYPE)

I had thought it would simply process the same numbers of lanes as the Double Species. I think it does, but it utterly crushes performance.

Is this question missing a tag? The code snippets are not java. The appropriate language tag should be added. Should this be tagged to [jvm] since using SIMD is more of a jvm than a java feature?

In some cases it's more efficient to take a slice of a matrix without copying it, just by having functions accept a matrix whose storage geometry differs from its width and height.  e.g. the stride (in elements) between rows can be different from the row width of the sub-matrix.  This is common in computer graphics, too, for sub-images.  Given a pointer to the top-left pixel / matrix element, a width, a height, and a row-stride, you can have a function work on a submatrix without copying.  (Or in Java where you don't have pointers, the pointer can be an array index into a flat 1D array.)

If you're going to do a lot with a sub-matrix and e.g. modify it in place, then yeah it can be better to copy it to compact storage.  It's a series of memcpy operations, one per row.  A double-nested loop would be a more efficient way to express it than a % inside the loop for scalar!  Or if Java has an efficient way to ask for a block copy, try that API instead of rolling your own with SIMD.  (Although SIMD-aware code can rounding up the copy size to a multiple of the vector width, and have the next row-copy partially overlap to overwrite the padding garbage you copied. Except the last row)
